# WinHttpSendRequest returns ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER

Tags: c, winapi

I am attempting to get the [betfair API](http://docs.developer.betfair.com/docs/display/) working with windows API.

I am stuck attempting to login with the following code (username and passwords have been changed).

```
char *headers = "X-Application: MakJhSABCDq8sbPIr\r\nAccept: application/json";

char *usernameandpassword = "username=mick&password=xyz123";

WinHttpSendRequest(
                    hrequest,
                    (LPCWSTR)headers,
                    -1,
                    usernameandpassword,
                    strlen(usernameandpassword),
                    strlen(usernameandpassword),
                    0);
```

but the call is returning with the value ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER. But I have no idea which parameter is bad.

Comment: This is what happens when you lie to the compiler. You lied when you said that your text was wide char.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LPCWSTR` as a typedef for `const wchar_t*`. On windows, that uses UTF-16 encoding.  Basically, you are type-casting an 8bit ASCII string (`headers`) to a 16bit wide string, and telling `WinHttpSendRequest()` to calculate the string length, which fails since it is not a valid wide string.

A solution to this is to use a proper wide string for the first place:

```
const wchar_t *headers = L"X-Application: MakJhSABCDq8sbPIr\r\nAccept: application/json";
```

Anyway, pointing to a string literal with a `char*` is wrong, since string literals are not modifiable, modifying them is undefined behavior. It should always be `const`.

Comment: AFAIK, there is nothing wrong using a non constant `char *` to access a string literal. The second part is true (they are not modifiable)

Comment: I didn't notice the compulsory wchar_t. Is my use of strlen() still ok?

Comment: @Mick yes. although in my opinion, there is really no point in using C for this.if you were to use C++ instead, most of these little pesky bugs will just go way without losing any performance.

Comment: @DavidHaim: How would C++ be of any help? Would `(LPCWSTR)headers.c_str()` really be any safer? Would it solve or prevent any bug?

Comment: `static_cast<LPWSTR>` will fail to compile. what you show is C-Style casting, not C++

Comment: @DavidHaim: So if that fails, you move on to the next cast: `reinterpret_cast<LPCWSTR>`. The issue isn't with the data types you use. The issue is, that you are calling a C interface. C++ only adds anything with respect to safety, if you already know what you're doing. There is no inherent gain in safety by using C++.