# WinHttpSendRequest continuously fails with windows error code 87, ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER (C++)

Tags: c++, http, winapi, winhttp

I am trying to send an http post request through a proxy that has headers and optionally, json content, using WinHTTP. I have tried solutions outlined in the questions here:

[WinHttpSendRequest failed with error code 87](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55459862/winhttpsendrequest-failed-with-error-code-87)

[WinHttpSendRequest returns ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39081237/winhttpsendrequest-returns-error-invalid-parameter)

However, it just does not seem to change anything. I have the post request functions pasted below. Perhaps there is something that I missed. Please let me know if there is anything I can do to fix this.

The problematic area is around WinHttpSendRequest

```
std::string PostRequest(std::wstring token, std::string json, std::string proxy, std::wstring url, std::wstring domain) {
    std::cout<<"PostRequest function started"<<std::endl;

    std::cout<<"json is being processed"<<std::endl;
    LPSTR  data = (LPSTR)json.c_str();
    DWORD data_len;
    if(data!=0) data_len = strlen(data); else data_len = 0;

    std::cout<<"json done"<<std::endl<<GetLastError()<<std::endl;

    std::string response;

    DWORD dwSize = 0;
    DWORD dwDownloaded = 0;
    LPSTR pszOutBuffer;
    BOOL  bResults = FALSE;
    HINTERNET  hConnect = NULL, hRequest = NULL;

    std::wstring stemp = std::wstring(proxy.begin(), proxy.end());
    const wchar_t* sw = stemp.c_str();

    std::cout<<"initializing WinHttpOpen"<<std::endl<<GetLastError()<<std::endl;

    HINTERNET hSession=WinHttpOpen(L"WinHTTP Example/1.0", WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY, L"http://"+*sw, WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0);

    std::cout<<"initializing WinHttpConnect"<<std::endl<<GetLastError()<<std::endl;

    if(hSession) hConnect = WinHttpConnect(hSession, domain.c_str(), INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT, 0 );

    std::cout<<"initializing WinHttpOpenRequest"<<std::endl<<GetLastError()<<std::endl;

    if(hConnect) hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest(hConnect, L"POST", url.c_str(), NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER, WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES, WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE);

    const wchar_t *additionalHeaders =
        L"Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
        L"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11\r\n"
        L"Authorization: "+*token.c_str()+*L"\r\n";
    DWORD headersLength = -1;

    std::cout<<"initializing WinHttpSendRequest"<<std::endl<<GetLastError()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"bResults: "<<bResults<<std::endl;

    LPVOID rqdata;
    if(data==0)rqdata = WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA;
    else rqdata=(LPVOID)data;

    if (hRequest) bResults = WinHttpSendRequest(hRequest, additionalHeaders, headersLength, rqdata, data_len, data_len, 0);
    else std::cout<<"else 1"<<std::endl;

    std::cout<<"bResults: "<<bResults<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"initializing WinHttpReceiveResponse"<<std::endl<<GetLastError()<<std::endl;

    if (bResults) bResults = WinHttpReceiveResponse(hRequest, NULL);
    else std::cout<<"else 2"<<std::endl;

    std::cout<<"bResults: "<<bResults<<std::endl;

    if (bResults)
        {
            do
            {
                // Check for available data.
                dwSize = 0;
                if (!WinHttpQueryDataAvailable(hRequest, &dwSize))
                    std::cout<<"Error in WinHttpQueryDataAvailable.\n"<<GetLastError();

                // Allocate space for the buffer.
                pszOutBuffer = new char[dwSize + 1];
                if (!pszOutBuffer)
                {
                    printf("Out of memory\n");
                    dwSize = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Read the data.
                    ZeroMemory(pszOutBuffer, dwSize + 1);

                    if (!WinHttpReadData(hRequest, (LPVOID)pszOutBuffer,
                        dwSize, &dwDownloaded))
                        std::cout<<"Error in WinHttpReadData.\n"<<GetLastError();
                    else
                        response = response + std::string(pszOutBuffer);
                    // Free the memory allocated to the buffer.
                    delete[] pszOutBuffer;
                }
            } while (dwSize > 0);
        }
        if (!bResults)
            std::cout<<"Error has occurred.\n"<<GetLastError()<<std::endl;

        if (hRequest) WinHttpCloseHandle(hRequest);
        if (hConnect) WinHttpCloseHandle(hConnect);
        if (hSession) WinHttpCloseHandle(hSession);

        return response;
}
```

all of the cout's are for debugging which will be removed by me later.

The output looks like this: (sorry if it is kind of messy)

```
PostRequest function started
json is being processed
json done
0
initializing WinHttpOpen
0
initializing WinHttpConnect
0
initializing WinHttpOpenRequest
0
initializing WinHttpSendRequest
0
bResults: 0
bResults: 0
initializing WinHttpReceiveResponse
87
else 2
bResults: 0
Error has occurred.
87
```

Comment: I suspect your `WinHttpOpen` call is failing already. The documentation says that the third argument must be `WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME` if the second argument is anything other than `WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_NAMED_PROXY`.

Comment: `GetLastError` must be called immediately after the function call that failed. You are calling it after, say, `std::cout<<"initializing WinHttpConnect"` which may call Windows API internally and reset the last error. Call it first thing, save the result in a variable, and then print that variable. Further, you should only call `GetLastError` if the function in fact fails, e.g. if `WinHttpOpen` returns NULL. Many API functions set last error when they fail, but don't clear it when they succeed, so `GetLastError` after a successful call may return a stale code from some previous call.